# angular routing - возможна ли реализация подстраниц?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

что есть:
стандартный ngApp с роутингом по примеру
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

что нужно:
в подгружаемой странице сделать тоже статичную часть, и подгружаемую часть, зависящую от URL. 
То есть: есть шапка и подвал - на всех страницах. на одной из страниц появляется какое-то еще меню, управляющее содержимым

Везде примеры самые простые, а с вложенными ngApp примера не нашел

Comment: `ng-include` разве нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше воспользуйтесь [UI Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/). С помощью этого компонента вы сможете добиться желаемого.

==== Пример ====

Шаблон файла index.html

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <ui-view></ui-view>
 </body>
</html>
```

Шаблон файла content.html

```
<ui-view name="header"></ui-view>
<ui-view name="content"></ui-view>
<ui-view name="footer"></ui-view>
```

Пример конфигурирования ui-router'а:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("app", {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/",
        controller: "AppController as vm",
        templateUrl: "app/views/content.html"            
    })
    .state("app.index", {
        url: "",
        data: { pageTitle: "Главная страница" },
        views: {
            "header": { templateUrl: "app/views/index/header.html" },
            "content": { templateUrl: "app/views/index/content.html" },
            "footer": { templateUrl: "app/views/index/footer.html" }
        }
    })
    .state("app.news", {
        url: "/news",
        data: { pageTitle: "Новости" },
        views: {
            "header": { templateUrl: "app/views/news/header.html" },
            "content": { templateUrl: "app/views/news/content.html" },
            "footer": { templateUrl: "app/views/news/footer.html" }
        }
    })
```

Что собственно происходит:

1) При старте приложения загружается состояние `app` и содержимое `content.html` загружается в `index.html`.

2) При загрузке url - `http://domain/` - загружается состояние `app.index`. При этом в файл `context.html` в соответствующие элементы по `name` загружаются *кусочки* страницы. Кусочки берутся по указанным в конфиге ссылкам.

3) При загрузке url - `http://domain/news` - загружается состояние `app.news`. При этом в файл `context.html` в соответствующие элементы по `name` загружаются *кусочки* страницы. Кусочки берутся по указанным в конфиге ссылкам.

Comment: на самом деле, сначала загружается состояние `app`

Comment: Да, Вы правы, торопился :)