# Проблемма с роутингом в Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация

Есть приложение, 3 страницы, index, /photo и /home
Фото, меняется контент в   и выполняется переход на новую страницу (domainname/photo) без перезагрузки. Проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопку обновить страницу в браузере, вываливаюсь в ошибку 404: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), урл domainname/photo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="exampleApps">
<head>
    <title>Routing</title>
    <script src="Libraries/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Libraries/angular_route.js"></script>
    <base href="http://urlrouting.loc/">

    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApps", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider.when("/photo", {
                templateUrl: "/photo.html"
            });
            $routeProvider.when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "/home.html"
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                templateUrl: "/home.html"
            });
        })
        .controller("defaultCtrls", function ($scope, $location) {   })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrls">

    <a href="/photo">photo</a>
    <a href="/view1">home</a>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А надо именно стандартный использовать? ui-router не подойдёт? посмотрите [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679523/angular-routing-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86)

Comment: @SergeyRogachev, и чем это должно было бы помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Исправил проблемму, нужно было настроить .htaccess, добавил такой код

```
//.htacces в корне домена
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html

DirectoryIndex /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что при обновлении страницы запрос с текущим путём отправляется на сервер. Сервер этот путь не узнаёт и отдаёт ошибку 404. Возможных решений два:

1. Использовать хэш-навигацию, при которой url страницы остаётся неизменным, а меняется только хэш, о котором сервер не знает. Для этого надо убрать строку

   ```
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   ```
2. Перенастроить сервер так, чтобы он по неизвестным путям (или по тем, которые есть в роутинге) отдавал эту страницу. В таком случае стоит настроить ангулярную 404.