# Как настроить Angular routes в комбинации с Zend Framework 2 (при условии, что ZF2 роутинг отключён) и Smarty (.tpl шаблоны)?

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация, smarty, zend-framework, angular-ui-router

Я использую Zend Framework 2, Smarty (шаблонизатор), AngularJS v1.6.4 и у меня следующая структура проекта:

```
project
    config
    data
    library
    module
        ...
        Application
            src
            config
            ...
            view
                Application
                    templates1
                    templates2
                    ...
                    templates5
                        ...
                        main.tpl
                    templates6
                        search.tpl
                        index.tpl
            module.php
    public
        css
        fonts
        ...
        js
            angular
                apps
                    MainApp.js
                controllers
                directives
                filters
                services
                config
                    route-config.js
                angular.js
                angular-ui-router.js
        .htaccess
        index.php
    composer.json
    composer.phar
    init_autoloader.php
```

P.S. route-config.js - это файл, содержащий $stateProvider, смотрите далее ниже

P.S.S main.tpl - основной шаблон, который содержит head, body, скрипты

Содержимое main.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="index-html" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/newstyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.uploadfile.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
{include file="../js/config.tpl"}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<div ui-view></div>
<!-- {$content} -->

<!--Angular, controllers, directives-->
<script src="/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="/js/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/apps/MainApp.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/services/interceptors/AnimationInterceptor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/config/run-config.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="/js/angular/controllers/index/IndexPageCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/controllers/search/SearchPageCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular/config/route-config.js"></script>
<!---->

</body>
</html>
```

P.S. {$content} в файле выше - это php-переменная, которая содержит в себе отрендеренный html-ответ, который приходит после перехода на какой-либо из урлов (/, /search, и т.д.), я его закомментировал, т.к. перевожу роутинг полностью на angular

И это route-config.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('search', {
                url: '/search',
                templateUrl: ''
            });
    });
```

Что мне нужно написать в templateUrl? Я не знаю, как правильно указать путь к файлу search.tpl (структура проекта выше), но более того, у меня не получается указать путь даже к созданному тестовому файлу в той же директории, в которой находится route-config.js
Относительные пути пробовал разные – не помогает, абсолютные пути тоже ни в какую. Возможно, я не имею представления, как нужно правильно прописывать путь, в веб-приложении, которое запущено на сервере, помогите мне, пожалуйста. P.S. Доступ к серверу прямой имею

Наверняка есть какие-то особенности в совмещении двух данных технологий в данной структуре проекта, которые нужно обязательно учесть.

Спасибо заранее, если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, спрашивайте

Comment: Чисто принципиально в templateUrl пишется путь до файла шаблона, до его физического размещения.

Comment: @SergeyRogachev Можете написать пример, пожалуйста

Comment: посмотри вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679523/angular-routing-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86/679572#679572). Я там расписывал работу с ``ui-router`` с примерами.

Comment: @SergeyRogachev я посмотрел, но не нашёл ответа. Дело в том, что ваш путь из примера "app/views/content.html" для меня является абстрактным и я не вижу всю файловую структуру. Где находится эта директория "app", кто её родитель?

Comment: @SergeyRogachev 
P.S. если нужно, вот физический путь до моего шаблона: /home/domains/dev.mysite.com/public/js/angular/config/test.html, я пробовал его указать в templateUrl, но всё равно в консоли выходит ошибка, о том, что невозможно найти файл: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /home/domains/dev.mysite.com/public/js/angular/config/test.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Comment: ``dev.mysite.com `` - это url вашего приложения? Попробуйте тогда ссылку сделать такую: ``public/js/angular/config/test.h‌​tml``

Comment: @SergeyRogachev 
Спасибо за помощь. Да, url таков.
Но к сожалению, ваш вариант не прокатил, в консоли две ошибки:
1) angular-ui-router.js:6691 Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: public/js/angular/config/test.h‌​tml (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
2) Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: public/js/angular/config/test.h‌​tml (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Comment: Уже и не знаю, на что думать... Обычный template срабатывает отлично, а вот templateUrl нивкакую не может найти указанный файл

Comment: А корневой ``state`` у Вас есть? Загрузка происходит следующим образом, в ``index.html`` загружается ``корневое`` состояние, которое содержит всю последующую разметку. У меня ощущение, что вы всё такие его не указали и соответственно, ``ui-router`` не понимает куда и что грузить. Под корневым понимается обычно ``state`` ``app`` с указанием свойства ``abstract: true``. Это говорит о том, что на данный ``state`` перейти нельзя. Посмотрите в примере по выше указанной ссылке.