# Как в Angular сделать переход между страницами без перезагрузки и без # в адресной строке?

Tags: angularjs, angular2, маршрутизация, angular-routing

Как в Angular сделать переход между страницами без перезагрузки и без # в адресной строке?

Comment: так angularjs или angular?

Comment: @Grundy в первую очередь для 4й версии

Comment: в 4й версии такое поведение по умолчанию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, воспользуйтесь следующим [решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679523/angular-routing-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86/679572#679572).

Убрать  `#` можно вот так:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

И не забыть сделать так:

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```